# To get total price of all the items in cart django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, cart

I am working on a project where everything works out aside some litle part of code which has to return the total price of items in the cart, but it only returns the price of the first item in the cart.

Here is the code, it doesn't add all the price in the loop.

models.py

```
class Item (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    d_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    tax = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    crated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', null=False, blank=False)
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', null=False, blank=False)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', null=False, blank=False)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', null=False, blank=False)
    image4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', null=False, blank=False)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class OrderItem (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"
    
    def total_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.price
    
    def total_d_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.d_price
    
    def saving(self):
        return self.total_price() - self.total_d_price()
    
    def get_total_price(self):
        if self.item.d_price:
            return self.total_d_price()
        else:
            return self.total_price()


class Order (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    
    @property
    def final_price(self):
        total = 0
        for order_item in self.items.all():
            total += order_item.get_total_price()
            return total
```

Comment: can you share `models.py`?

Comment: @HemalPatel please do check just edited